# Launching NodeJS Knockout SPA from Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, knockout.js

I created a project using **yo ko** and opened in Visual Studio 2012 with NTVS.

The app runs fine from command line using **http-server src**

But hitting F5 on Visual Studio simply launches Node and doesn't start a server and browser pointing to the SPA app.

I realized I needed a "server.js" script to start the server. So I copied this example from somewhere:

```
var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.port || 1337;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(port);
```

Obviously this is writing a simple text.

Question is, how do I make it run a server on the src folder, as http-server is doing?

I looked in http doc for nodejs but couldn't find something to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be simple: created a new blank ASP.Net project. On console, navigated to the new project directory, and ran "yo ko".

Added the files to the project in VStudio and set the starting file as index.html.